# Usage of Mutex in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, mutex

I am a bit new in threading in **c#** and on general,
in my program I am using `mutex` to allow only 1 thread getting inside a critical section and for unknown reason with doing some cw prints I can see that more than 1 thread is getting inside my critical section and this is my code :

```
Mutex m = new Mutex();
m.WaitOne();
<C.S> // critical section here
m.ReleaseMutex();
```

I would very much like to know if I am doing a mistake here thanks in advance for your kind help.

**EDIT:**

My code include classes so it basically looks more like this:

```
public class test
{
    private mutex m;
    public test()
    {
         m = new mutex();
    }
    public func()
    {
         m.WaitOne();
         <C.S> // critical section here
         m.ReleaseMutex();
     }


    }
```

Comment: You must have more than one instance of the class.

Comment: That is an instance-level mutex; are you sure your coding isn't in the critical section on separate unrelated instances? Also, any error will render the code permanently locked - you need a `try`/`finally` for that to be safe.

Comment: After the Edit: this Mutex works only at the object level, ie 1 CrticialSection / instance. Is that what you want?

Comment: Info: `Mutex` is `mutual exclusion`

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The problem here is that all your callers are using a **different** mutex; you need the locking object to be *shared*, usually by making it a field. For example, and switching to a simpler `lock` metaphor:

```
private readonly object syncLock = new object();
public void ThreadSafeMethod() {
    lock(syncLock) {
        /* critical code */
    }
}
```

or using the mutex:

```
private readonly Mutex m = new Mutex();
public void ThreadSafeMethod() {
    m.WaitOne();
    try {
        /* critical code */
    } finally {
        m.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}
```

Comment: the mutex that i am using is a global mutex of a class so i think that it is the same mutex

Comment: @Nadav - that is not what your question shows... your question shows it as the same location as code, i.e. a local variable.

Comment: Nadav - are you sure you don't have more than one instance of the class?  Almost all 'lock/mutex is letting multiple calls through' problems turn out to be that there are more lock/mutex objects than you intended.

Answer (score 5):

This pattern does no locking at all. Every thread creates a new Mutex object and immediately owns the lock for it. Other threads create and use a new Mutex itself.

Consider using a regular lock()!

```
lock(_lockobject) {
   // do inside what needs to be done - executed on a single thread only
}
```

where _lockobject is a simple private variable in your class:

```
private object _lockobject;
```

Edit: thanks to the commenters! Situations exist, where lock(this) can be dangerous. So I removed that.

Comment: Do not `lock(this)`, or `lock(someType)`, or `lock(anyString)` - those are bad designs and are not robust.

Comment: BTW, locking this is not allways good idea, better is create simple variable of type object http://www.toolazy.me.uk/template.php?content=lock%28this%29_causes_deadlocks.xml

Comment: lock(this) is not considered to be good practice.  (See, for example http://haacked.com/archive/2006/08/08/ThreadingNeverLockThisRedux.aspx).  Much better to make an Object just for locking on, and forget that the .NET design error that lets any object be locked on was ever made.

Comment: @WillDean - indeed; I'd rather that there was a specific type, for example `Monitor` instances. Also, `object` should be `abstract` ;p

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you give each Thread its own Mutex. That won't work.

And a Mutex is overkill in most situations. You only need:

```
private static object syncLock = new object();  // just 1 instance

....

lock(syncLock)
{
    // critical section
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure from the question that we can infer `static` is intended... although we can't infer that it *isn't* either ;p

Comment: @Marc, correct. I used static as the opposite of what I _think_ is the error. The code is not entirely clear.

Answer (score 2):

Mutex use to identify run app instance.

```
 using (Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true, "app name", out createdNew))
            {
                if (createdNew)//check app is already run
                {
                    KillOthers();
                    StartApp();
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Another instance already running!");
                }
            }
```

Answer (score -2):

May i add a correction to the accepted answer?

```
private readonly Mutex m = new Mutex();
public void ThreadSafeMethod() {
    while(!m.WaitOne()){}
    try {
        /* critical code */
    } finally {
        m.ReleaseMutex();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Emanuele. Why do you think that your answer is an improvement? The loop: `while (!m.WaitOne()) { }` is never going to run more than once, because the [`WaitOne`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.waithandle.waitone#System_Threading_WaitHandle_WaitOne) method with no arguments always returns `true` (unless it never returns).