# Synchronize output from 100 threads

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have 100 threads and I want to make sure that at a time max three threads run in sequence they created.

i.e.

I have numbers from 1 to 100. I want to print it like below

```
Thread1
Thread2
thread3
'
'
'
```

But at a time only three threads are allowed. Once any of thread from 1,2,3 is completed. Next thread in sequence should start.

I know we can do using semaphoreslim but would be interested to know answer with Mutex or some other way.

Suppose I have application which can server maximum 3 requests at a time. But i get 100 requests and want to server them in FIFO order with maximum 3 at a time. Hope this clears the doubt,

Comment: `Once any of thread from 1,2,3 is completed. Next thread in sequence should start.` I'm not too clear what you're asking for. Are you wanting to run 100 threads in sequence? If so, why?

Comment: If threads have to complete in sequence, there's no point using them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Usage of Mutex in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754879/usage-of-mutex-in-c-sharp)

Comment: consider a scenario where my application gets 1000 requests but i want to make sure to serve only 3 requests at a time in FIFO order. I just gave an example to 100 threads and numbers.

Comment: I am not sure with the above Usage of Mutex in c#.

Comment: _"to serve only 3 requests at a time in FIFO order"_ - look at _[semaphore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore(v=vs.110).aspx)_.  I can't see how a  `Mutex` will help

Comment: you can use a semaphore or mutex to achieve that. In my case i run a async task controlled by the semaphore. if the max number of task are done, the semaphore would release and queue again.

Comment: Don't synchronize 100 threads, synchronize 3 threads that all pull from a thread safe queue of 100 items to be processed.

Answer (score 1):

To have a maximum of three threads running at the same time, a pool of threads of size three should be used. You should implement a thread pool pattern that queues the execution requests in a FIFO queue and have a maximum limit of three requests executing at the same time.

The thread pool will guarantee your requests **start** execution in the same order since it uses a FIFO queue. However, this does not guarantee they will **finish** execution in the same order.

Comment: I am saying that using a thread pool is the solution to the problem.

Comment: @MickyDuncan As long as you do not know why the poster specified exactly three threads, then you do not know if this is an ideal solution or not. This solution is the ideal solution to control the number of concurrent threads executing at the same time. Also multi-threading is independent of the number of cores!

Comment: That was in reply to your deleted comment. I have edited my answer anyway.

Comment: That looks better.  Downvote removed.  Wishing you a good weekend

Answer (score 0):

You should save yourself the pain of using raw threads and opt for a framework that does all of the hard lifting for you.

I would suggest using Mircosoft's Reactive Framework (NuGet "Rx-Main") for this. The code is super simple:

```
var subscription =
    Observable
        .Range(0, 100)
        .Select(n => Observable.Start(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            return n;
        }))
        .Merge(maxConcurrent: 3)
        .Subscribe(n => Console.WriteLine(n));
```

With this code I get this result:

```
1
3
2
0
5
6
7
4
8
9
...
95
97
96
98
99
```

You can stop the computation by calling `subscription.Dispose();`.

Comment: @SuyogShah - Not if they run on different threads. You want them to run on different threads **and** be in order?