# Locking method only for 2 threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking, mutex

I have following code:

```
public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
{
    lock (_lockObj)
    {
       // ... some HTTP job that can take 5 to 30 seconds ...
    }
}
```

When an active job is working and a second thread enters the same method, I want it locked for second thread and wait.. However, when it is already locked for a second thread, and then a 3rd thread enters the code, I want it exit the method instead of waiting and entering job execution.

I could use a static counter variable and increase/decrease its value by the thread count within job execution. But I wonder if there is already a better practice to solve this issue.

Comment: careful. that is *not* how a mutex works, that is how an ordinary lock works. please take a good look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754879/usage-of-mutex-in-c-sharp

Comment: from what you were describing, it would seem likely that you were actually looking for an actual Mutex :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are looking for [`System.Threading.Semaphore`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx).

```
var sem = new Semaphore(0, 2);
```

That creates a semaphore with an initial value of zero and a maximum of two. Up to two threads will be able to call `sem.WaitOne()` without blocking. After that, threads that call `sem.WaitOne()` will block until another thread calls `sem.Release()`.

There is an overload [`WaitOne(int timeout)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189907.aspx) that accepts a timeout parameter. If zero is passed for the timeout, the call will not block, and return immediately. The boolean return value indicates whether or not you successfully acquired the semaphore. In your case, if it returns False, you simply abort the operation.

Comment: I'm not sure how this will provide what i needed.. This will allow always  two threads are actively working and leave the rest in a wait state. What i need is not something like allowing 2 threads running at the same time.. I want only one thread working already.. But if there is already a "Thread-2" locked and waiting in line for the "Thread-1", the "Thread-3" should be canceled and exit the method, not wait...

Comment: @Noldor You're right, I forgot that part. I've updated my answer with a reference to `WaitOne(int timeout)` which should serve you well.

Comment: Oh yes, now that makes sense =) Thank you, I'll implement this soon and see the results.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [Semaphore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z6zx288a(v=vs.110).aspx) with a capacity of 2.