# Create a queue of async tasks - using BlockingCollection C#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, task, tweetinvi

I have a WPF C# application, which sends out a message to both Facebook and Twitter using the API. To do so I have one main static class where I can send the string  message and a few parameters. The code works fine when the user only sends out announcements intermittently.  But when the user sends out multiple announcements at once it doesn't work. What I want is:

- Do on announcement one at a time in a FIFO order
- Not to disrupt the GUI
- Allow requests to be queued.
- Allow requests to be made any where in the program & at any time

I have looked into using BlockingCollection, but not had much luck understanding how to make it work.

This is my current code and I would like it as close to this as possible:

```
class PublishAnnouncement {
 //This function is callled upon in many parts of the program and acts as a general publisher
 public static void PostAnnoucment(string message, string TwAccountKey, string FbAccountKey, string[] JourneyRefID, double latness, MainWindow mainWindow) {
  //First it is published to facebook
  BackgroundWorker FacebookWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
  FacebookWorker.DoWork += (obj, e) => FacebookDoWork(message, FbAccountKey);
  FacebookWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

  //Then it is published to twitter - This is where it appears to fail
  BackgroundWorker TwitterWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
  TwitterWorker.DoWork += (obj, e) => TwitterDoWork(message, TwAccountKey, JourneyRefID, latness, mainWindow, 0);
  TwitterWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
 }

 private static void FacebookDoWork(string message, string FbAccountKey) {
  //STAGE 1 - Facebook
  //First the program will attempt to post a Facebook post.
  try {
   //If it is to be posted by one of the additional Facebook Pages and 
   //not by the default page.

   var client = new RestClient("https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/");

   var request = new RestRequest("{pageId}/feed", Method.POST);
   request.AddParameter("message", message); // adds to POST or URL querystring based on Method
   request.AddParameter("access_token", Properties.Settings.Default.FBPageAccessToken);
   request.AddUrlSegment("pageId", Properties.Settings.Default.FBPageID); // replaces matching token in request.Resource
   IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);

   if (response.IsSuccessful == false) {
    Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
    Console.WriteLine("");
   }

  } catch (Exception ex) {
   Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
  }
 }

 private static void TwitterDoWork(string message, string TwAccountKey, string[] JourneyRefID, double latness, MainWindow mainWindow, int Attempts) {
  //STAGE 2 - Twitter
  //Once a Facebook post has/has not been posted the program will attempt to send a tweet.
  try {

   Auth.SetUserCredentials(Properties.Settings.Default.TwConsumerKey, Properties.Settings.Default.TwConsumerSecret, Properties.Settings.Default.TwUserAccessToken, Properties.Settings.Default.TwUserAccessSecret);
   var tweet = Tweet.PublishTweet(message);
   foreach(var ID in JourneyRefID)
        AddTweetID(tweet.Id, ID, latness, mainWindow);


  } catch (Exception ex) {
   foreach(var ID in JourneyRefID)
        AddTweetID(0, ID, latness, mainWindow);

   Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using a Mutex in PostAnnouncement.
See the accepted answer here   - use the lock example:
[Usage of Mutex in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754879/usage-of-mutex-in-c-sharp)

```
class PublishAnnouncement {
private static readonly object syncLock = new object();

public static void PostAnnoucment(string message, string TwAccountKey, string FbAccountKey, string[] JourneyRefID, double latness, MainWindow mainWindow) {
    lock(syncLock) {
        //First it is published to facebook
        BackgroundWorker FacebookWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        FacebookWorker.DoWork += (obj, e) => FacebookDoWork(message, FbAccountKey);
        FacebookWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

        //Then it is published to twitter - This is where it appears to fail
        BackgroundWorker TwitterWorker = new BackgroundWorker();
        TwitterWorker.DoWork += (obj, e) => TwitterDoWork(message, TwAccountKey, JourneyRefID, latness, mainWindow, 0);
        TwitterWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

        //etc
    }
}
```

}

the lock will allow only one thread through at a time, stacking up all threads. Note I've made the lock static.
(no matter how many instances of the class are in use at any one time, only one lock object is made and referenced by all calling threads).

If you want to move the locks into the background threads:

```
class   PublishAnnouncement {
private static  readonly    object  syncLockForTwitter  =   new object();
private static  readonly    object  syncLockForFacebook =   new object();
//This  function    is  callled upon    in  many    parts   of  the program and acts    as  a   general publisher
public  static  void    PostAnnoucment(string   message,    string  TwAccountKey,   string  FbAccountKey,   string[]    JourneyRefID,   double  latness,    MainWindow  mainWindow) {
    //First it  is  published   to  facebook
    BackgroundWorker    FacebookWorker  =   new BackgroundWorker();
    FacebookWorker.DoWork   +=  (obj,   e)  =>  FacebookDoWork(message, FbAccountKey);
    FacebookWorker.RunWorkerAsync();

    //Then  it  is  published   to  twitter -   This    is  where   it  appears to  fail
    BackgroundWorker    TwitterWorker   =   new BackgroundWorker();
    TwitterWorker.DoWork    +=  (obj,   e)  =>  TwitterDoWork(message,  TwAccountKey,   JourneyRefID,   latness,    mainWindow, 0);
    TwitterWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
}

private static  void    FacebookDoWork(string   message,    string  FbAccountKey)   {
    lock(syncLockForFacebook)   {
    //STAGE 1   -   Facebook
    //First the program will    attempt to  post    a   Facebook    post.
        try {
            //If    it  is  to  be  posted  by  one of  the additional  Facebook    Pages   and 
            //not   by  the default page.

            var client  =   new RestClient("https://graph.facebook.com/v3.0/");

            var request =   new RestRequest("{pageId}/feed",    Method.POST);
            request.AddParameter("message", message);   //  adds    to  POST    or  URL querystring based   on  Method
            request.AddParameter("access_token",    Properties.Settings.Default.FBPageAccessToken);
            request.AddUrlSegment("pageId", Properties.Settings.Default.FBPageID);  //  replaces    matching    token   in  request.Resource
            IRestResponse   response    =   client.Execute(request);

            if  (response.IsSuccessful  ==  false)  {
                Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }

        }   catch   (Exception  ex) {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}

private static  void    TwitterDoWork(string    message,    string  TwAccountKey,   string[]    JourneyRefID,   double  latness,    MainWindow  mainWindow, int Attempts)   {
    lock(syncLockForTwitter)    {
    //STAGE 2   -   Twitter
    //Once  a   Facebook    post    has/has not been    posted  the program will    attempt to  send    a   tweet.
        try {

            Auth.SetUserCredentials(Properties.Settings.Default.TwConsumerKey,  Properties.Settings.Default.TwConsumerSecret,   Properties.Settings.Default.TwUserAccessToken,  Properties.Settings.Default.TwUserAccessSecret);
            var tweet   =   Tweet.PublishTweet(message);
            foreach(var ID  in  JourneyRefID)
                                AddTweetID(tweet.Id,    ID, latness,    mainWindow);


        }   catch   (Exception  ex) {
            foreach(var ID  in  JourneyRefID)
                                AddTweetID(0,   ID, latness,    mainWindow);

            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer, I have implemented it, however, should I remove my background workers and make them a task? As I worry currently wont a new message start trying to send before the background workers have completed? If so how would I change them from a background worker to a task and use Wait without freezing the GUI. Sorry I'm very new to threading.

Comment: You can do anything you want. One way would be to move the static lock into the background workers.