# How to create pdf with image and chart where the image is on the left side of the chart?

Tags: c#, winforms, pdf

I'm using the library package itext7 and also installed itext7.bouncy-castle-adapter

I want to create a pdf file with a chart and image and the image will be position near the chart on the left side.

this is the code I tried:

```
private void CreatePdf(string imagePath)
{
    string pdfPath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(imagePath), "Output.pdf");

    using (var pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(pdfPath))
    {
        using (var pdf = new PdfDocument(pdfWriter))
        {
            var document = new Document(pdf);

            // Create a table with two cells
            var table = new Table(2);
            table.UseAllAvailableWidth();

            // Add chart image to the first cell
            MemoryStream chartStream = new MemoryStream();
            chartHistogram.SaveImage(chartStream, ChartImageFormat.Png);
            var chartImage = new iTextImage(iText.IO.Image.ImageDataFactory.Create(chartStream.ToArray()));
            var chartCell = new Cell().Add(chartImage);
            table.AddCell(chartCell);

            // Add image from PictureBox to the second cell
            MemoryStream imageStream = new MemoryStream();
            pictureBoxImage.Image.Save(imageStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
            var imageElement = new iTextImage(iText.IO.Image.ImageDataFactory.Create(imageStream.ToArray()));
            var imageCell = new Cell().Add(imageElement);
            table.AddCell(imageCell);

            // Add the table to the document
            document.Add(table);

            // Add text information
            Paragraph text = new Paragraph("Additional text information about the histogram and image.");
            document.Add(text);
        }
    }

    MessageBox.Show($"PDF created successfully: {pdfPath}", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

but the result is that the chart a bit too much to the right and the image is nowhere at all.

[image: pdf]

the output result should be like this:

with the text in the bottom "Additional text information about the histogram and image."

and make the image and the chart bigger but this is the format I want it to be like in the created pdf file.

[image: pdf where the image is on the left side of the chart.]

Comment: Please add an image of the expected output to your post. Also, you haven't specified what library (and version) you're using to create the PDF.

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76392303/10024425

Comment: @user246821 edited and updated my question with the information.